# Can we use Azure PaaS resources like Azure Data Factory or Azure Functions in a private cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, private-cloud

I'm new to cloud computing. I'm trying to figure out the difference between public and private clouds. I understand that in a private cloud, the organization owns and maintains the infrastructure. Is this to say that private clouds are always IAAS and cannot use PaaS services?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project that was using Azure Functions on Azure Stack (private cloud). The only thing we had to do, was making sure the Storage Account was v1 not the v2. Besides that, everything worked as expected.

PS: I'm not sure about Azure Data Factory.